# WooCommerce Add to Cart Button & Price Hidden

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, themes

I'm working on a WordPress site (using a child theme of Divi) & having an issue with the WooCommerce Shop. The individual Product pages are not displaying the Add to Cart button or the price. Those elements are there (I can highlight over them on the page & click the area where the button should display) but they're hidden for some reason. Anyone know how to make them display?

Here is an [example page](http://thesockkids.com/shop/books/destination-imagination-anti-bullying-story/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I saw your product page, It just a CSS issue, put the following css snippet on your theme's `style.css`

```
.woocommerce button.button.alt {
    background-color: #a46497 !important;
}

.woocommerce div.product p.price, 
.woocommerce div.product span.price {
    color: #77a464 !important;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!